# Update links in all excel files within folder

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I'm fairly new to writing VBA macros and I'm sure I'm making a stupid mistake..
So I worked out this piece of code from bits I found on the internet to try and automate updating links to all files within a particular folder.
When I try to run it I get the following error:

> 'Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment'.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Sub ChangeLink()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim mergeObj As Object
Dim folderObj As Object
Dim filesObj As Object
Dim everyObj As Object

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folderObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("W:\Finance\01 Draft2")
Set filesObj = folderObj.Files

For Each everyObj In filesObj
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filesObj, UpdateLinks:=0)

ThisWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:="W:\06 Dec 19 AEF.xlsx", NewName:="W:\Finance\07 Jan 20 AEF.xlsx", Type:=xlExcelLinks

ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
ThisWorkbook.Close

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks braX, but no it's in the same line in the actual code.

Comment: `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook with the code in it. You want to work with `wb`. I'm not sure `.Saved` does what you want either.

Comment: Thank you. So i replaced ThisWorkbook with wb and removed the .Saved line and still results in the same error.

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: There is no line in particular, nothing highlighted just a general error message when i click the run button..

Comment: filesObj should be everyObj in this line Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filesObj, UpdateLinks:=0). Also ChangeLink is not a good choice of name as it is also a workbook method. Better would by MyChangLinks.